# Define that protocol implementing classes must inherit from some super class

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a static library which contains a class with the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic) Class deserializationClass;
```

Is there a way to define that this `deserializationClass` must be inherited from some super class say `MySuperClass`. I intend to tell the user of the SDK that class object you pass must be inherited from super class provided by the library.

I was wondering if protocols could help here. Is there a way we can define in a protocol that implementing classes must inherit from this super class? Or is there any other solution to my question?

Comment: Why don't you simply define the property like `@property (nonatomic) MySuperClass deserializationClass;`. Then `deserializationClass ` must be of type `MySuperClass`.

Comment: Presumably he intends to create instances of the class with an expression like `[[self.deserializationClass alloc] init]`. That requires a class object.

Comment: @robmayoff You got it right. I intend to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C has no way to express this.

Note that `UIView` has the same problem. It has the `layerClass` class method, which must return a `Class` that subclasses `CALayer`, but it can't specify this at compile-time. Instead you get a runtime error if you override `layerClass` and don't return a subclass of `CALayer`.

Your alternative is to require the user to pass in a factory object rather than a class. Example:

```
@protocol MyFactory

- (MySuperClass *)newInstance;

@end

@interface MyStaticLibraryObject

@property (nonatomic) NSObject<MyFactory> *deserializationFactory;

@end
```

Now the user has to provide an instance of a class that conforms to `MyFactory`, and you can send it `newInstance` to get something that implements `MySuperClass`.

Comment: Ah, too bad there's nothing for this in Objective-C. A great dynamism but some potholes maybe.